# Dialog flow V2 API Get URL https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/{parent=projects/projId}/agentName 404

Tags: google-api, dialogflow-es

Am trying to update dialogflow version for my existing chatbot, but when I am framing url like above, it gives me 404 error. Help me to build the URL.

Comment: Is the Url in the title the exact Url that you tried to call?

Comment: @gmolau No, it is a sample which is given by google, here is the document url:
https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects/getAgent

Comment: But did you specify your project_id correctly, i.e. like this: `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE/agent`?

Comment: @gmolau, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The {} notation is the [Google API HTTP annotation syntax](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto) used by Google to indicate that the {} should be replaced by a parameter. In this case, that parameter is named `parent`, so you can reference it in the documentation below, and it should have the form `projects/*` where the `*` should be replaced with your project ID.

So the actual URL you want to use is something more like

```
GET https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/your-project-id-here/agent
```

Comment: Thanks prisoner for the explanation.